# Make bootstrap 3 container content full height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Any ideas on how to make a div inside a bootstrap container full height? I need the background to be white all the way down, like the image below.

[image]

Here's my code so far:

**index.html**

```
<div class="container white_background_filler">
    <row>
        <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nulla mi, finibus sit amet urna ut, commodo suscipit ligula. Curabitur ut finibus libero. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam ac hendrerit lorem. Donec ultrices et tortor at porta.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    </row>
```

**style.css**

```
body {
   margin: 10px;
   background: #ccccff;
   height: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   border: 1px solid #f0f;
}

.white_background_filler {
   background-color: #fff;
   height: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   /*border: 1px solid #f00;*/
}

footer {
   background: #FFF;
}
```

Use fiddle to fork a solution if that makes it easier to respond: https://jsfiddle.net/tuxedojoe/w47g7pbd/

Comment: try `min-height: 100vh` in `.jumbotron`, may it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really all you need is to set the viewport height e.g. `min-height: 100vh`.  See the code snippet for a working example.  Hope this helps.

```css
body {
   margin: 10px;
   background: #ccccff;
   height: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   border: 1px solid #f0f;
}

.white_background_filler {
   background-color: #fff;
   min-height: 100vh;
   /*border: 1px solid #f00;*/
}

footer {
   background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="container white_background_filler">
    <row>
        <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nulla mi, finibus sit amet urna ut, commodo suscipit ligula. Curabitur ut finibus libero. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam ac hendrerit lorem. Donec ultrices et tortor at porta.</p>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nulla mi, finibus sit amet urna ut, commodo suscipit ligula. Curabitur ut finibus libero. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam ac hendrerit lorem. Donec ultrices et tortor at porta.</p>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nulla mi, finibus sit amet urna ut, commodo suscipit ligula. Curabitur ut finibus libero. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam ac hendrerit lorem. Donec ultrices et tortor at porta.</p>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nulla mi, finibus sit amet urna ut, commodo suscipit ligula. Curabitur ut finibus libero. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam ac hendrerit lorem. Donec ultrices et tortor at porta.</p>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nulla mi, finibus sit amet urna ut, commodo suscipit ligula. Curabitur ut finibus libero. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam ac hendrerit lorem. Donec ultrices et tortor at porta.</p>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nulla mi, finibus sit amet urna ut, commodo suscipit ligula. Curabitur ut finibus libero. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam ac hendrerit lorem. Donec ultrices et tortor at porta.</p>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nulla mi, finibus sit amet urna ut, commodo suscipit ligula. Curabitur ut finibus libero. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam ac hendrerit lorem. Donec ultrices et tortor at porta.</p>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nulla mi, finibus sit amet urna ut, commodo suscipit ligula. Curabitur ut finibus libero. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam ac hendrerit lorem. Donec ultrices et tortor at porta.</p>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nulla mi, finibus sit amet urna ut, commodo suscipit ligula. Curabitur ut finibus libero. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam ac hendrerit lorem. Donec ultrices et tortor at porta.</p>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nulla mi, finibus sit amet urna ut, commodo suscipit ligula. Curabitur ut finibus libero. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam ac hendrerit lorem. Donec ultrices et tortor at porta.</p>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nulla mi, finibus sit amet urna ut, commodo suscipit ligula. Curabitur ut finibus libero. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam ac hendrerit lorem. Donec ultrices et tortor at porta.</p>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nulla mi, finibus sit amet urna ut, commodo suscipit ligula. Curabitur ut finibus libero. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam ac hendrerit lorem. Donec ultrices et tortor at porta.</p>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nulla mi, finibus sit amet urna ut, commodo suscipit ligula. Curabitur ut finibus libero. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam ac hendrerit lorem. Donec ultrices et tortor at porta.</p>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nulla mi, finibus sit amet urna ut, commodo suscipit ligula. Curabitur ut finibus libero. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam ac hendrerit lorem. Donec ultrices et tortor at porta.</p>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nulla mi, finibus sit amet urna ut, commodo suscipit ligula. Curabitur ut finibus libero. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam ac hendrerit lorem. Donec ultrices et tortor at porta.</p>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nulla mi, finibus sit amet urna ut, commodo suscipit ligula. Curabitur ut finibus libero. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam ac hendrerit lorem. Donec ultrices et tortor at porta.</p>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nulla mi, finibus sit amet urna ut, commodo suscipit ligula. Curabitur ut finibus libero. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam ac hendrerit lorem. Donec ultrices et tortor at porta.</p>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nulla mi, finibus sit amet urna ut, commodo suscipit ligula. Curabitur ut finibus libero. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam ac hendrerit lorem. Donec ultrices et tortor at porta.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    </row>
```

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion and that does it, until I get text longer than the viewport (100vh). See updated fiddle with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/tuxedojoe/w47g7pbd/

Comment: Then just set the `min-height: 100vh` - see the updated snippet.  Also you could have used CSS flexbox, which is a very neat way of styling such containers and offers more advanced control. Maybe have a look at it.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
.col-xs-8, row{
     height: 100%;
}
```